# Can ClaimRow() be used to generate a unique ID for a Data Extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, cloudpage, smart-capture

I want to generate a unique ID in a Data Extension each time a record is created via SmartCapture using Cloud Pages.

I am trying to use the `ClaimRow()` function to do this by pulling the unique ID from another Data Extension but unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work when I add the AMPscript to the SmartCapture form:

```
%%[
VAR @UniqueID
SET @UniqueID = ClaimRow("UniqueIDs", "IsClaimed")
IF EMPTY(@UniqueIDs) THEN ]%%
No Unique IDs available
%%[ ELSE ]%% 
Your Unique ID is %%= FIELD(@UniqueID,'UniqueID') =%%
%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

Is there another way to auto-generate a unique id for a new Data Extension record?  Or does someone know where exactly the AMPscript should be placed in the SmartCapture form?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about generating a unique ID, it can be achieved by using the GUID() AMPscript function.

An example: `%%=GUID()=%%`

Result: **bc9c9237-9604-410d-89e6-4653bf15e008**

Reference: [GUID](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/GUID.htm)